# How to concatenate a string in my case using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, concatenation

I have 4 column in one table called **RelationRecord**

**RelationRecord**

```
Parent    Child1    Child2    Child3
------------------------------------
111        111       null      111
222        null      null      null
null       333       null      null
null       null      null      444
555        555       555       555
```

I wants to do concatenate and separate by comma like below

**Expecting output**

```
111,111
222
333
444
555,555,555,555
```

I tried using `case` and `isnull` but it doesn't work. When I use case,the query will become a lot. Is there any alternative solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select stuff( (coalesce(',' + child1, '') +
               coalesce(',' + child2, '') +
               coalesce(',' + child3, '') +
               coalesce(',' + child4, '')
              ), 1, 1, ''
             )
```

The `stuff()` is used to remove the leading comma (if any) in the result column.

Comment: what is that `1,1`?

Comment: @mohamedfaiz . . . arguments to `stuff()`.

Comment: it's working. please give me the defination of `coalesce` also please.. I will accept answer after 8 min. Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql

Answer (score 1):

If 2012+, another option is `concat()`

**Example**

```
Select NewValue = IsNull( stuff( concat( ','+Child1
                                        ,','+Child2
                                        ,','+Child3
                                       ),1,1,''),Parent)
 From YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
NewValue
111,111
222          -- Notice Parent is displayed
333
444
555,555,555
```

Answer (score 0):

I´m not proud of this, but does the trick

```
 select 
isnull(cast(Parent as varchar(19)),'') + 
case  
    when Parent is null then ''
    when Child1 is null then '' 
    else ',' end + 
isnull(cast(Child1 as varchar(59)),'')  + 
case  
    when Child1 is null then ''
    when Child2 is null then '' 
    else ',' end +
isnull(cast(Child2 as varchar(59)),'') + 
case  
    when Child2 is null then ''
    when Child3 is null then '' 
    else ',' end +
isnull(cast(Child3 as varchar(59)),'')from Table_1
```